# MVC 3. Load menu and content separately

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe

I have an app with 3 sections:

- Main menu;
- Context Menu - Related to selected item in main menu;
- and Page body - Related to selected item in context menu;

"Main menu" and "Context menu" are based on membership. I don't want to load them everytime my page loads, because that would consume resources database. So, I'm using ajax to load main menu only one time, and when an item is selected, I load the context menu for that item.

My problem is: Every form's post will erase my menu.

Question: Will I have to build my entire application using ajax? I don't wanna do that, because it is too much simpler do a post in the form then send all data to controller with ajax.

Until now, I have 2 options:

1. Load my menus with ajax and the page body with IFRAME, so the post's will not render again my menus.
2. Do everything using ajax;

Is there any alternative to load my menus with ajax and be able to use form's post?

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence that gave me a pause is this "I don't want to load them everytime my page loads, because that would consume resources database."

You see, I've build quite a lot of apps, that display menus and sub-menus based on user roles (what you called membership). This has never been an issue from the resources or database perspective.

You can access all the membership information that you need *once*, when your used is being logged in. In the simplest case user's identity will be stored in the context along with the roles they have (HttpContext.User), so you do not to need a database lookup at all to get this information on every request. Note that with this scenario no ajax is required either.

If for whatever reason you can't store your membership information in the context like this, you still can store in in session (if in-memory) or in encrypted Cookies.

Now, I understand, that I don't all the details of your scenario, and that may be in your scenario what you are trying to do is warranted, however I suggest you think it through again, as under normal circumstances what you indicate is a problem (database resource) should not be a problem at all.

The bottom line is: if you alter your application that it stores the membership information when user logs on you won't have your problem to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t have to build all of your application using Ajax. But in this scenario Ajax may be the best way forward.

Following is my suggestion

1. Create your data entry for inside a dev
2. Have each input controller marked with a class (say ‘dataEntry’)
3. Create a javascript function to iterate the dev and build a list of all elements that has class  dataEntry
4. Build a json object using the list. Use the name of each element as property name and value as the property value
5. Use jquery ajax to post this to the controller action
6. [optional] you can use .done and .fail methods to take action on success or failures of the call

I know this may look intimidating, but if you have many data entry forms, you can re-use this code.